# Só primeira linha da tabela sendo exibida!

Tags: php, sql

Estou solicitando os dados da tabela deste jeito:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` order by `userid` DESC";
$limite = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($limite)) {
    $account_id = $sql['account_id'];
    $userid = $sql['userid'];
    $sex = $sql['sex'];
    $email = $sql['email'];
    $group_id = $sql['group_id'];
    $last_ip = $sql['last_ip'];
}
echo '
<table class="vertical-table th">
    <tr align="center">
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>ID</b></font></th>
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Login</b></font></th>
      <th width="25%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Sexo</b></font></th>
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Email</b></font></th>
      <th width="25%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Level</b></font></th>
      <th width="20%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>IP</b></font></th>
    </tr>
<tr align="center">
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#009900" size="2">'.$account_id.'</font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>'.$userid.'</b></font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2">'.$sex.'</font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2">'.$email.'</font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#E41B17" size="2">'.$group_id.'</font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#000099" size="2">'.$last_ip.'</font></p></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Testando a query diretamente no banco de dados funciona perfeitamente, porém ná página só retorna a primeira linha...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É apenas exibir os valores do último registro porque seu `echo` está depois do `while`, se quer imprimir todos os registros jogue o código para dentro do laço.

```
while ($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($limite)) {
    $account_id = $sql['account_id'];
}
echo '
//... mais código
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">
<font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>'.$userid.'</b></font></p></td>
```

Pode corrigir ao fazer interpolação do PHP com HTML:

```
<table class="vertical-table th">
    <tr align="center">
      <th width="10%">ID/th>
      <th width="10%">Login</b>/th>
    </tr>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` order by `userid` DESC";
    $limite = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    while ($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($limite)) {
       $account_id = $sql['account_id'];
       $userid = $sql['userid'];
?>
       <tr align="center">
          <td><?php echo $account_id; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $userid; ?></td>
       </tr> 
<?php 
    } 
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Não entendi a diferença, teria como exemplificar um pouco melhor?

Comment: @Guilherme respondendo de uma forma bem prática, você consegue achar ótimos exemplos nessa documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/tutorial.php Caso ainda não encontre pode consultar aqui: http://aprenderphp.com.br/. Mesmo assim sei que é uma documentação um pouco avançada mais acho que você ira conseguir entender como funciona um While

Comment: Perfeito! Agora eu entendi xD Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: @Guilherme, seu `echo` que imprime a tabela está fora do `while` isso quer dizer ele vai ser executado apenas uma vez diferente dos comandos dentro do while que vão executar várias vezes.

Answer (score 3):

Para utilizar todos os dados que veem da Base de Dados tens de imprimi-los em todas as iterações do `while`, ou seja, enquanto houverem linhas a virem da Base de Dados tu imprimes as linhas da tabela no HTML.

```
echo '
<table class="vertical-table th">
    <tr align="center">
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>ID</b></font></th>
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Login</b></font></th>
      <th width="25%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Sexo</b></font></th>
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Email</b></font></th>
      <th width="25%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Level</b></font></th>
      <th width="20%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>IP</b></font></th>
    </tr>
';    

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` order by `userid` DESC";
$limite = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($limite)) {
    $account_id = $sql['account_id'];
    $userid = $sql['userid'];
    $sex = $sql['sex'];
    $email = $sql['email'];
    $group_id = $sql['group_id'];
    $last_ip = $sql['last_ip'];

    echo ' 
    <tr align="center">
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#009900" size="2">'.$account_id.'</font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>'.$userid.'</b></font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2">'.$sex.'</font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2">'.$email.'</font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#E41B17" size="2">'.$group_id.'</font></p></td>
      <td>
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#000099" size="2">'.$last_ip.'</font></p></td>
    </tr>
   ';
}   
echo'</table>';
```

Comment: Deve seguir o conselho da resposta do @rray sobre interpolação de PHP com HTML. Fica mais simples e mais fácil de ver onde realmente fazemos alguma coisa dinâmica.

Comment: Entendido. Mas ambas respostas foram perfeitas muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O `while` é o comando que percorre os registros da sua consulta. Você precisa por ele na parte específica da `table` que deseja repetir, no seu caso, ficaria algo do tipo:

```
echo '
<table class="vertical-table th">
   <tr align="center">
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>ID</b></font></th>
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Login</b></font></th>
      <th width="25%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Sexo</b></font></th>
      <th width="10%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Email</b></font></th>
      <th width="25%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>Level</b></font></th>
      <th width="20%">
      <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>IP</b></font></th>
   </tr>
   ';

   while ($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($limite)) {
      $account_id = $sql['account_id'];
      $userid = $sql['userid'];
      $sex = $sql['sex'];
      $email = $sql['email'];
      $group_id = $sql['group_id'];
      $last_ip = $sql['last_ip'];

      echo '
      <tr align="center">
         <td>
         <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#009900" size="2">'.$account_id.'</font></p></td>
         <td>
         <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><b>'.$userid.'</b></font></p></td>
         <td>
         <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2">'.$sex.'</font></p></td>
         <td>
         <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" size="2">'.$email.'</font></p></td>
         <td>
         <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#E41B17" size="2">'.$group_id.'</font></p></td>
         <td>
         <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><font face="Verdana" color="#000099" size="2">'.$last_ip.'</font></p></td>
      </tr>
      ';
   }
echo '</table>';
```